# Why it is oveflow in contador in ada?

Tags: ada

I dont know why the prove is error at the overflow in the variable contador. I need help.

```
 contador: Integer;
   J: Integer;

   function noPrimos (lista : My_Array) return Boolean

   with
      Global  => contador,
      --Depends => ...,
      Pre     => True and contador < Integer'Last,
      Post    => (noPrimos'Result = True or noPrimos'Result = False);  



FILE ADB

function noPrimos (lista : My_Array)  return Boolean is
      contador: Integer;
   begin
      for I in lista'Range loop
         contador:= 0;
         if lista(I) /= 1 then
            for J in 1.. lista(I) loop
               if lista(I) rem J = 0 then
                  contador := contador + 1;
               end if;
            end loop;
            if contador <= 2 then
               return false;
            end if;
         else
            return true;
         end if;
         pragma Loop_Variant(Increases => I);
      end loop;
      return true;
   end noPrimos;
```

The problem is the overflow the result:
Phase 1 of 2: generation of Global contracts ...
Phase 2 of 2: flow analysis and proof ...
15:40: medium: overflow check might fail (e.g. when contador = 2147483647)
47:40: medium: overflow check might fail (e.g. when contador = 0)

Comment: It looks as though `noPrimos` returns `True` if there are no more than 2 non-primes in the list or any member of the list is 1. Difficult to think of any requirement that would justify such a postcondition!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I assume that the function `noPrimos` will return `True` only if the list `lista` does not contain any primes. That being said, I'm a little bit puzzled by some aspects of the code snippet:

- The type definition of `My_Array` is missing.
- The role of the global instance of `contador` (english: counter) is not clear from the given code snippet. By writing `Global=> contador`, you state that the global variable `contador` will be read by the function `noPrimos` (see also [here](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-spark/book/02_Flow_Analysis.html#global-contracts)), but that doesn't happen because the local instance of `contador` shadows the global instance of `contador`.
- The reason for the variable `J` being defined globally is not clear, you can omit it.
- The precondition `True` (on the left side of the Boolean operator `and`) is trivial and can be omitted.
- The postcondition states that the result of `noPrimos` can either be `True` or `False`. This is trivial as `noPrimos` returns a boolean and can therefore be omitted. The postcondition should state the function's expected result given its inputs.
- The loop variant `pragma Loop_Variant(Increases => I);` is trivial as the variable `I` will increase by the definition of the for-loop. Hence the loop variant can be omitted.

Below is an example of a function `No_Primes` that searches the given list `L` for primes and returns `True` if none are found. It proves in GNAT CE 2019:

**primes.ads** (spec)

```
package Primes with SPARK_Mode is

   type List is
     array (Natural range <>) of Positive;

   --
   --  Returns True if N is a prime number (or False otherwise).
   --
   function Is_Prime (N : Positive) return Boolean
     with
       Global => null,
       Post => Is_Prime'Result =
         (if N = 1 then False
            else (for all I in 2 .. N - 1 => N rem I /= 0));  

   --
   -- Returns True if list L does not contain any prime numbers (or False otherwise).
   --
   function No_Primes (L : List) return Boolean
     with
       Global => null,
       Post => No_Primes'Result =
         (for all I in L'Range => Is_Prime (L (I)) = False);

end Primes;
```

**primes.adb** (body)

```
package body Primes with SPARK_Mode is

   --------------
   -- Is_Prime --
   --------------

   function Is_Prime (N : Positive) return Boolean is
   begin
      if N = 1 then
         return False;
      else
         for I in 2 .. N - 1 loop

            if N rem I = 0 then               
               return False;
            end if;

            pragma Loop_Invariant
              (for all J in 2 .. I => N rem J /= 0);

         end loop;
      end if;
      return True;
   end Is_Prime;

   ---------------
   -- No_Primes --
   ---------------

   function No_Primes (L : List) return Boolean is
   begin

      for I in L'Range loop

         if Is_Prime (L (I)) then
            return False;
         end if;

         pragma Loop_Invariant
           (for all J in L'First .. I => Is_Prime (L (J)) = False);

      end loop;
      return True;

   end No_Primes;

end Primes;
```

A small test program (**main.adb**)

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Primes;      use Primes;

procedure Main is

   --  Some test vectors.
   L1 : List := (1 => 1);         --  Expect TRUE  : 1 is not a prime.
   L2 : List := (1, 2, 3, 5, 7);  --  Expect FALSE : All are prime except 1.
   L3 : List := (2, 3, 5, 7);     --  Expect FALSE : All are prime.
   L4 : List := (1, 4, 6, 8, 9);  --  Expect TRUE  : None are prime.
   L5 : List := (4, 6, 8, 9);     --  Expect TRUE  : None are prime.
   L6 : List := (3, 4, 5);        --  Expect FALSE : 3 and 5 are prime.

begin
   Put_Line ("No_Primes (L1) = " & Boolean'Image (No_Primes (L1)));
   Put_Line ("No_Primes (L2) = " & Boolean'Image (No_Primes (L2)));
   Put_Line ("No_Primes (L3) = " & Boolean'Image (No_Primes (L3)));
   Put_Line ("No_Primes (L4) = " & Boolean'Image (No_Primes (L4)));
   Put_Line ("No_Primes (L5) = " & Boolean'Image (No_Primes (L5)));
   Put_Line ("No_Primes (L6) = " & Boolean'Image (No_Primes (L6)));
end Main;
```

yields

```
No_Primes (L1) = TRUE
No_Primes (L2) = FALSE
No_Primes (L3) = FALSE
No_Primes (L4) = TRUE
No_Primes (L5) = TRUE
No_Primes (L6) = FALSE
```